# Normalisation, confused

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to incorporate normalization into my database design, some of the explanations available on the internet have got me slightly confused - and I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction here?

So far I have:

users:

```
id 
username 
password
```

userprofilesettings:

```
id 
userid 
active 
dateofreg
```

userbusinessinfo:

```
id 
userid 
businessname 
tags
```

contactinfo:

```
id 
userid 
address 
postcode 
email 
tel
```

categorytags:

```
id 
userid 
services
```

Comment: Why not describe what these relations mean to us and explain your thinking. That way we can point you in the right direction if necessary.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you are trying to do.  There are a variety of things that you could normalize but more info is needed.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the standard 3NF.

Comment: Jimmy, this looks pretty good. Every "entity" (i.e. person,place,thing,concept or event which is of interest and we store information about) should be a separate table, with a primary key (looks like you've added `id` as surrogate key. Everything there looks good. What remains is determining which attributes (fields) belong with which entity, which attributes may be repeated (create a separate child table for repeating attributes), and defining the relationships between the entities (one-to-many, many-to-many).

Answer (score 1):

address will get an own table

```
contactinfo
==========
id
userid
idaddress
postcode
email
tel

address
==========
idaddress
street
houseNumber
postalCode
city
country
```

...

good basics : http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
**userbusinessinfo**
id
userid
businessname
tags
```

What does tags hold? It sounds like more than one value, in which case you should have a `UserBusinessInfoTags` table. You should also use camel case for fields and proper case for table names for clarity of reading.

```
**UserBusinessInfoTags**
id
userBusinessInfo_id
tag
```

What does `UserProfileSettings` hold? If it is a one-to-one relationship with user, the table could be merged with user.

`ContactInfo` can be split out. Is the user allow to have multiple address, multiple emails, and multiple telephone numbers? Each should have its own table them. If not, combine it with `Users`. For instance, if they can have multiple phone numbers and addresses, but not emails, it would look like.

```
**Users**
id
username
password
email

**UserAddresses**
id
userId
addressLine1
addressLine2
city
state
zipCode
country

**UserPhoneNumbers**
id
userId
phoneNumber
phoneNumberType
```

Comment: UserProfileSettings would hold information such as, if the account is active or not, the date the account was created, a radius (for a distance field). The tags does have its own table, 'CategoryTags'.

Users cannot have more than one address, or multiple telephone numbers. I figured seperating the company information from the user itself was the best solution.

Comment: In the case of `CategoryTags`, then you need a many-to-many table to map those to `UserBusinessInfo` i.e. `tagId`, `businessId`.

Answer (score 0):

Normalisation is about reducing the number of times a particular piece of data will be stored. You can go too far with normalisation as the more normalised your database is the less performant it will be.

In the extreme cases of a flat file vs fully normalised you would be getting a single record from one sql hit vs potentially 10 or 20 or even more records from other tables.

How far you normalise (3rd normal form is the ideal IMO but others will disagree) depends entirely on the app and it's complexity.

With the exception of addresses as pointed out by @duffy356 I'd say you have it about right.